# How to random numbers in php between two block and make the results unique?

Tags: php

I need to create 2 blocks and each block contain number between 1-3. how can i achieve this with php?

the results should be:

- 1-1
- 1-2
- 1-3
- 2-1
- 2-2
- 2-3
- 3-1
- 3-2
- 3-3

many thanks for your help

Comment: suggestion: you can use nested for loop

Comment: How is that random? Random usually meas 'not predicable'. What have you tried?

Comment: rand(1, 3); but i need the result to be unique

Answer (score 2):

Nest for loops and echo the loop values.

```
For($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){ //outer loop 
    For($j=1;$j<=3;$j++){ // inner loop
        Echo $i ."-".$j ."\n"; // echo inner value and outer value 
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/2Kqbl

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by random, but to get the desired out put you can use nested for loop.

```
$m=3;
$n=3;
for($i=1;$i<=$m;$i++){
    for($j=1;$j<=$n;$j++){
       echo $i .'-'. $j."\n";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested for loop Example:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 3 ; $i++){
    for($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++){
       echo $i .'-'. $j."\n";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

depends on what do you want to be the relation between that 2 "blocks" or what they are propose for... what you have posted there can be made like this:

```
$rand = rand(0,3);
for($x = 0; $x <= 9; $x++;){
echo $rand."-".$rand; echo"<br>";
}
```